# How to run erlang (rebar build) application

Tags: erlang, rebar

I am new to Erlang world and currently can't figure out how to start my dummy erlang application. Probably, I am just missing something... So, I created an application with rebar (rebar create-app appid=dummys).

Currently I have

- rebar.config
- src/dummys.app.src
- src/dummys_app.erl
- src/dummys_sup.erl

I have found that in order to run an application during a development it is better to create an additional start method which should call application:start(module).

I added some basic logging to my start methods..

```
start() ->
    error_logger:info_msg("Starting app(dev)..~n"),
    application:start(dummys_app).

start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->
    error_logger:info_msg("Starting app..~n"),
    dummys_sup:start_link().
```

If I try

```
erl -noshell -pa ebin -s application start dummys
erl -noshell -pa ebin -s application start dummys_app
```

there are no output..

If I try

```
erl -noshell -pa ebin -s dummys start
```

erl crashes with an error..

If I try

```
erl -noshell -pa ebin -s dummys_app start
```

it outputs just "**Starting app(dev)..**" and that's all. But I also expect to see "**Starting app..**"

What I am missing or doing wrong??

=============

**And another question:** How to add a new module to my dummy application correctly? For example I have an additional module called "*dummys_cool*" which has a "*start*" method. How to tell my application to run that "dummys_cool#start" method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For quick development, if you just want to ensure your appliction can start, start a shell, then start the application:

```
erl -pa ebin
1> dummys_app:start().
```

That will give you a clean indication of what is wrong and right without the shell bombing out after.

Since you're making an application to run, rather than just a library to share, you'll want to make a release. Rebar can get you most of the way there:

```
mkdir rel
cd rel
rebar create-node nodeid=dummysnode
```

After you've compiled your application, you can create a release:

```
rebar generate
```

This will build a portable release which includes all the required libraries and even the erlang runtime system. This is put by default in the rel/ directory; in your case rel/dummys.

Within that directory there will be a control script that you can use to start, stop, and attach to the application:

```
rel/dummys/bin/dummys start
rel/dummys/bin/dummys stop
rel/dummys/bin/dummys start
rel/dummys/bin/dummys attach
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation! Finally, I figured out how it works all together.

Comment: This is solid advice. It appears that the semantics has changed a bit with rebar3. The documentation is great (https://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases). Specifically check out {dev_mode, true}.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at your `dummys.app.src` file. The meaning of all the directives is explained in [the 'app' manpage](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/app.html), but the one I suspect is missing here is `mod`, which indicates the name of your application callback module.  So make sure that this line is present:

```
{mod, {dummys_app, []}}
```

The empty list in there will be passed as the `StartArgs` argument to `dummys_app:start/2`.

---

To make a new module start along with your application, add it to the supervision tree in `dummys_sup:init`.  This function should look something like:

```
init(_) ->
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 10, 10},
         [{dummys_cool, {dummys_cool, start_link, []},
           permanent, brutal_kill, worker, [dummys_cool]}]}.
```

This is described in [the 'supervisor' manpage](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html), but basically this means that on startup, this supervisor will start one child process. `dummys_cool:start_link()` will be called, and that function is expected to spawn a new process, link to it, and return its process id.  If you need more processes, just add more child specifications to the list.

Comment: Thank you @legoscia. I've checked my app.src file and mod is there
`{application, dummys,
 [
  {description, "dummy application"},
  {vsn, "1"},
  {registered, []},
  {applications, [
                  kernel,
                  stdlib
                 ]},
  {mod, { dummys_app, []}},
  {env, []}
 ]}.`

Answer (score 1):

```
erl -noshell -pa ebin -s application start dummys
```

The code above will not work because `application:start([dummys])` will be called.

You can take a reference of the [Erlang documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) for details.

For your case,

```
erl -noshell -pa ebin -s dummys
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem, and this was the first answer on Google.

If you are using rebar3, the standard configuration will have a `shell` command that compiles your project and opens a shell:

```
$ rebar3 shell
===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling myapp
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.2.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1]

Eshell V10.2.4  (abort with ^G)
1> ===> Booted myapp
```